# How to have a Discord bot return the number of words in a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'args-info') {
      if (!args.length) {
        return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
      } else if (args[0] === 'foo') {
        return message.channel.send('bar');
      }

      message.channel.send(`Command name: ${command}\nArguments: ${args}`);
      message.channel.send(`Second argument: ${args[1]}`);
      message.channel.send(`Arguments: {}`);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the part that is relevant to the question.

If you message the bot *"Here are my arguments what do you think about that?"*, I want it to return:

```
Command name: args-info
Arguments: here,are,my,arguments,what,do,you,think,about,that
Second argument: are
**Arguments Length: 10**
```

I need to figure out the command that counts the number of words in a sentence and change this: `` message.channel.send(`Arguments: ${}`); ``

I'm not familiar with Discord.js functions and which one can count a character string. I will look some more but I haven't found anything yet. The reason I ask is this person put it as an example in his code but he never shows the code of how to return the answer and I'm just curious.

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is already an array of the words, so you can print the [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of that. It will return the number of elements (words in this case) in that array.

```js
message.channel.send(`Arguments length: ${args.length}`);
```

You can find some comments in the following code to explain it better:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  // args is an array of all the words
  // including "args-info"
  const args = message.content
    // .slice() removes the prefix from the message content
    .slice(prefix.length)
    // .trim() removes spaces from both ends
    .trim()
    // .split() creates a new array by dividing the string
    // it splits the string everywhere it finds one or more spaces
    .split(/ +/);

  // the shift() method removes the first element
  // it removes args-info in this case
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'args-info') {
    if (!args.length) {
      return message.channel.send(
        `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`,
      );
    }
    if (args[0] === 'foo') {
      return message.channel.send('bar');
    }

    message.channel.send(`Command name: ${command}`);
    message.channel.send(`Arguments: ${args}`);
    message.channel.send(`Second argument: ${args[1]}`);
    // args.length is the number of words
    message.channel.send(`Arguments length: ${args.length}`);
  }
});
```

And it seems to be working as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just send this message, it should give you the intended result.

```js
message.channel.send(args.join(','));
```

To get character count you can do

```js
message.channel.send(args.join(',').length);
```

**References**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length
- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send